# The meaning of (n) in a SQL query?

Tags: mysql, sql

```
SELECT COURSENAME
FROM COURSE C1
WHERE (1) IN
(SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT(C2.COURSEFEES))
FROM COURSE C2
WHERE C2.COURSEFEES > C1.COURSEFEES);
```

What is the meaning of this 'WHERE (1) IN'?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is an awkward way of writing:

```
WHERE (SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT C2.COURSEFEES)
       FROM COURSE C2
       WHERE C2.COURSEFEES > C1.COURSEFEES
      ) = 1
```

This is saying that there is one course fee larger than the one in the record -- or alternatively that the course fee is the second largest.

It might be simpler to see this as:

```
WHERE C1.COURSEFEES = (SELECT C2.COURSEFEES
                       FROM COURSE C2
                       GROUP BY C2.COURSEFEES
                       ORDER BY C2.COURSEFEES DESC
                       LIMIT 1 OFFSET 1
                      )
```

Answer (score 3):

Parentheses in `(1)` are superfluous, so it could only be `1 IN ...`.

`1 IN X` essentially is the same as `X = 1`.

Since the query which replaces `X` returns a count, it checks if the count returned by the correlated subquery equals 1

---

This query is equivalent, but rewritten into `X = 1` instead of `1 IN X`:

```
SELECT COURSENAME
FROM COURSE C1
WHERE (
  SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT(C2.COURSEFEES))
  FROM COURSE C2
  WHERE C2.COURSEFEES > C1.COURSEFEES
) = 1;
```

It compares every course fee with other fees to return only these, that have only one larger fee than the one we're comparing at the moment, thus

```
count(distinct(..)) = 1 for c2.coursefees > c1.coursefees
```

Answer (score 0):

Here WHERE (1) is comparing to resultant count from the inner query.

If below inner query returns one 1 then outer query will fetch output else no output.

```
(SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT(C2.COURSEFEES))
FROM COURSE C2
WHERE C2.COURSEFEES > C1.COURSEFEES)
```